# Node throwing an error on ansi module

Tags: node.js

I'm looking to check out Mike Bostock's [Rivers](https://github.com/mbostock/us-rivers), but I'm running into an error with Node.js. `npm install` gives me:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'ansi'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js:5:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Any pointers? Or, any previous questions I missed that might point to a solution?

Comment: Did you update your node version when this happened?

Comment: did you use homebrew?  Why not use the osx version of node from nodejs.org

Answer (score 1):

If you run on RH CentOS of Fedore reinstall

yum reinstall nodejs-ansi.noarch

This fixed my similar issue

Answer (score -2):

You can run:

```
npm install ansi -g
```

to make ansi available globally (you may have to use `sudo`)